# Executing the same stored procedure in parallel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which calculates payroll data (total gross, total deductions, tax and net pay) for employees in different companies. The stored procedure works fine and returns all the correct data if it is executed asynchronously.

However the stored procedure does not work properly when it is executed by several users at the same time. The stored procedure executes without any errors however it does not return the correct data for example it does not return the net pay and the tax calculated is incorrect when it is executed synchronously.

The main stored procedure contains several nested stored procedures and all stored procedures use (delete/update/insert/select) temporary tables.

Grateful if you can help me find a solution so that the stored procedure can be executed synchronously and returns the correct data.

I am using SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.5698.0) Enterprise edition.

Comment: When you say temporary tables to you mean temp tables like #temptable, global temp tables like ##temptable or tables that are physical tables that you use temporarily and clear?

Comment: Without knowing better what the procedures are doing, we can offer little to suggest the problem here. Perhaps you are using `NOLOCK` and thus reading rows you don't want to (but said you want to).

Comment: `Nolock` would have been my *guess*, but no one can offer any suggestions blind.

Comment: You might well need to serialise these operations, one way is using `sp_getapplock`.

Comment: @Bee_Rii, I am using physical tables which are cleared each time the SP is executed.

Comment: @Larnu, I am not using any locks.

Comment: As multiple versions of the proc are running they will be all writing to the same physical tables.  If you need to run multiple instances of the proc you should use either temp tables or table variables that way they are only in scope for the specific run of the proc.  If you do use temp tables make sure to drop them at the end so they don't continue to use space in your temp db.

Comment: @Bee_Riii we are using a unique id to write, update or delete to the physical tables. won' t it cause performance issues if we use temp tables?

Comment: No you shouldn't have any performance issues as long as you set up your temp tables appropriately.   In fact you'll probably see it runs better.  

Though if you are using unique keys throughout and getting different results this makes me think that either your unique keys are unique or when returning results your not filtering on that unique key.  In any case there is definitely an issue with the design somewhere.